# How to read voice mails programmatically in Android

Tags: android, voicemail

Just wonder whether it's possible to access phone's voice mail box using code?

I have seen in Android 4.0, Google has introduce a new content provider called "`android.provider.VoicemailContract.Voicemails`" but I want to do this on older versions of Android? Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 1):

No, because each network operator/phone manufacturer handles voicemail differently. In many cases, there won't even be any app on the phone that knows about individual voice messages. The best you can do is create a PhoneStateListener to listen for [`LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR), which lets you read the message waiting indicator flag sent by the network operator (answers the question "Are there any new voice messages?").